# regex digits formatting

Tags: javascript

I want to use regex specifically! to check if a mobile number contains 9 or more digits. I am a little unsure as to how to format this exactly.

I want to check inside an if statement like the below

```
if(mob >= (.{9})
```

This is clearly not correct, any help would be great

Comment: Please add sample data showing what these mobile numbers look like.

Comment: Apologies, one mobile number is "0750617965789"

Comment: Do the phone numbers always consist exclusively of digits?

Comment: Some begin with +

Answer (score 1):

Use `test` with the regex pattern `^\+?[0-9]{9,}$`:

```js
var number = "+123456789";
if (/^\+?[0-9]{9,}$/.test(number)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check of numbers not for all the characters. And also use `test()` to check if string matches regex or not.

```js
const testMob = str => /^\+?[0-9]{9,}$/.test(str);

console.log(testMob('+123456789')) //true
console.log(testMob('+1234567890')) //true
console.log(testMob('+133333'))  //false
```

Comment: More info from OP, update to `^\+*(\d){9,}$` to include the optional plus sign

Comment: @JasonB That pattern is incorrect, and would allow for any number of leading `+`.  I'm pretty sure the OP only expects at most one `+`.

Comment: Right you are, should be ? instead of *. `^\+?(\d){9,}$`